# multiple component of the same type render only one instance

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I am rendering two sorting components and I am passing an array from the parent to those two children components as props to apply different sorting algorithms. The problem is when I am using the fillArray method inside the componentdidMount method in the parent component which will take the array and display it in the dom, only the last sorting component takes effect but the other sorting components don't update their own dom to show the bars !!!

This is the child component

```
class sorting extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: [],
      bars: NumberOfBars,
      firstSelection: "Insertion",
      btn: false,
      dual: true,
    };
    this.bubbleSort = this.bubbleSort.bind(this);
    this.fillArray = this.fillArray.bind(this);
  }

 fillArray() {
    console.log("from the fill array ");
    this.setState({ array: this.props.array });
  }

 render() {
    const { array } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <Container>
        <h1>{`component-${this.props.id}`}</h1>
        <div className="theContainer">
          {array.map((value, idx) => (
            <div
              className={"theBar " + this.props.id}
              key={idx}
              style={{ height: `${value}px` }}
            ></div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.bubbleSort}>sort</button>
        <button onClick={this.fillArray}>reset</button>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the parent component

```
class MainPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            array: [],
            temp: [1, 2, 3]

        };
        this.child = React.createRef();
    }
    // generating the random numbers

    randomNumber(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        let result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        return result;
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.resetTheArray();
        this.onClickFillArray();
    }
    resetTheArray() {
        const temp = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            temp.push(this.randomNumber(5, 750));
        }
        // must use this method to concatinate the new element to the array inside the state
        this.setState({ array: temp });
    }
    onClickFillArray = () => {
        this.child.current.fillArray();
    }
    onClickBubbleSort = () => {

    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar ></NavBar>
                {this.state.temp.map((e) => (<Sorting key={e} ref={this.child} id={e} array={[...this.state.array]} />))}
                <button onClick={this.onClickFillArray}>click here</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.onClickBubbleSort()}>Sort me </button>
            </div >
        )
    }

}
```

**What happens when the App Mounts
[Wrong behavor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8f7E.png)
What I want to happen
[Correct behavor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOssJ.png)

I am assuming that when my parent component mounts it will update the dom of each sorting component but somehow react only updates the dom of the last sorting component!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in your only creating one `ref` (`this.child`). That one `ref` is assigned to each `Sorting` element in your `map`, but since it is only one `ref`, each subsequent assignment effectively overwrites the previous one. The `ref` will accordingly always reference the last `Sorting` element to which it is assigned in the `map`. As a result, the first two `Sorting` elements never have their arrays filled; without any data, they never print any charts.

To fix the issue, try assigning a unique `ref` to each `Sorting` element.

Comment: Do you know how can that be achievable ?? assigning a unique ref for each sorting component?

Comment: To generate a unique ref for each Sorting element, you would need to call CreateRef() once for each ref. If you know how many sorting elements you need from the outset, you could just do it statically in the constructor (`const childRef1 = CreateRef(); const childRef2 = CreateRef(); ...). If they need to be assigned dynamically, you could store them in an array as you create them.

Comment: If the refs are stored in an array, then you could access them by index in your `map` that creates the `Sorting` elements.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the refs, though. You could just store the Sorting elements directly in the parent class.

Comment: Yeah, that works like a charm, thank you !!! the reason why I am separating the sorting component is that I am going to have a navbar that will have a selection tag that shows which algorithm must be executed and an additional toggle switch that decides if you want to show two components and make them race against each other I am sure I can manage that without separating each component but I just want it to be neat!

Comment: Great! Glad it is working. If you found that solution helpful, would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks!